# What difference between @load() and ${}

Tags: el, zk, ref

code:

```
<zk>
    <vbox r="@ref(1)">
        <label value="${empty r}" />
        <label value="@load(empty r)" />
    </vbox>
</zk>
```

returns:

```
true
false
```

${} not working with @ref()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer : no it doesn't.

First, if you want automatic updates of values use `@load(...)` because static expressions in `${...}` are only evaluated once.

Second, bind annotations @init/@load are being computed later in the ZK Bind lifecycle than the static EL expressions.

So ZK first tries and evaluate your `${empty r}`, at this time r is not defined so `${empty r}` is null.
Then later in the lifecycle it'll handle the databinding annotations @.